# Wanna clear some of my confusion related to tokenURI and baseURI

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, ipfs

i wanna clear my confusion on tokenURI.

1. Suppose i uploaded a metadata folder to IPFS and got this URI for the metadata folder: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmaG1LkBd9N9EsAqANbzdZtZxrSqGcT4v7Qqjw8CDDLCCa/. Now this whole url is baseURI??
2. To get tokenURI we will the `tokenURI()` of openzeppelin ERC721 where the baseURI will be concatenated with tokenId. This tokenURI gives the metadata of a particular file, means for the provided url the tokenURI is: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmaG1LkBd9N9EsAqANbzdZtZxrSqGcT4v7Qqjw8CDDLCCa/1.json, am i right??

Comment: Yes you are correct
Check out my comment on your previous post.